# Npm: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js' on UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I am getting below error while using **npm install**

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/sbin/npm:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/sbin/npm:155:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using relative path while using npm

Do :

```
which npm -a
```

It should give an output like `/usr/bin/npm`

Then use absolute path for npm and that is **/usr/bin/npm**

It should work.